# Как удалить программно созданный View?

Tags: java, android

Хочу сделать приложение "список покупок". При нажатии на кнопку "Добавить" в LinearLayout добавляю новый LinearLayout с текстом(EditText) (название покупки) и кнопкой "Del":

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParamsBtn = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParamsItem = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

LinearLayout llItem = new LinearLayout(this);
llItem.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

EditText etItem = new EditText(this);
etItem.setText(etTitle.getText().toString());
etItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

llItem.addView(etItem,lParams);

Button btnDelete = new Button(this);
lParamsBtn.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
btnDelete.setText("Del");
btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
llItem.addView(btnDelete,lParamsBtn);

llList.addView(llItem,lParamsItem);
```

Но я не знаю, как удалить теперь эти элементы при нажатии кнопки Del. Ведь при создании элементов я не задавала ID и, как я поняла, ID можно задать только целочисленным. И нужно кнопки Del тоже отличать одну от другой. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это лучше реализовать. В крайнем случае можно было бы задавать целым числом(по-моему, я видела метод для удаления по ID), но мне кажется, это неправильно.

Comment: У llItem разве нет команды removeView или что-то типо того?

Comment: А вообще лучше делать список через RecyclerView  и при добавлении обновлять его иначе при большем наборе таких View чем вы наполняете сейчас ваше приложение будет тормозить

Comment: У LinearLayout есть метод removeView, но он удаляет по имени объекта, мне же нужно что-то типа id, чтобы удалить конкретный по счету элемент, а так же и кнопки del должны как-то отличаться друг от друга, чтобы я могла удалить именно соответствующую строку. По поводу RecycletView спасибо, почитаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кнопку вы добавляете прямо в элемент списка, поэтому будет нетрудно получить родительский вид кнопки и удалить его. Судя по фрагменту вашего кода, класс реализует интерфейс `View.OnClickListener`, поэтому добавьте в метод `onClick` несколько строк:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    View item = v.getParent(); //элемент списка - родительский вид по отношению к кнопке
    ViewGroup list = (ViewGroup) item.getParent(); //список, он же llList
    list.removeView(item); //удаляем элемент списка
}
```

Таким образом, вам не нужно будет хранить **никакой информации** об элементе, который вы собираетесь удалить, её можно получить от кнопки.

**UPD**

Используйте [`ArrayList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList) и `View.indexOfChild`:

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>(); //объявление и инициализация
/*
*
*
*/
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParamsBtn = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParamsItem = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

LinearLayout llItem = new LinearLayout(this);
llItem.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

EditText etItem = new EditText(this);
etItem.setText(etTitle.getText().toString());
etItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

llItem.addView(etItem,lParams);

Button btnDelete = new Button(this);
lParamsBtn.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
btnDelete.setText("Del");
btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
llItem.addView(btnDelete,lParamsBtn);

llList.addView(llItem,lParamsItem);

//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Добавляем данные
data.add(""MyDataString);
```

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    View item = v.getParent(); //элемент списка - родительский вид по отношению к кнопке
    ViewGroup list = (ViewGroup) item.getParent(); //список, он же llList

    data.remove(list.indexOfChild(item)); //удаляем данные
    list.removeView(item); //удаляем элемент списка
}
```

Однако этот способ требует, чтобы в списке `llList` находились только те элементы, которым соответствуют данные в списочном массиве `data`

Comment: Спасибо!!! Хотя все-таки странно, что нельзя задавать строковые id для элементов...

Comment: Я сейчас подумала, а если я захочу в массиве хранить те же данные, я же не смогу узнать, какая конкретно по счету запись была удалена. Хотя, наверное, можно как-то получить дочерние элементы списка и посчитать порядковый номер, просто как-то мне это кажется немного странным.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не знаю, приходят ли Вам оповещения о моих комментариях, я здесь недавно. Вы не могли бы еще подсказать, как мне быть, если хочу хранить в массиве эти данные? Например, нажала я Del, как мне узнать, какую по порядку запись я хочу удалить? Пока что пришло в голову только каждый раз считывать все дочерние элементы llList с помощью getChildAt(i) и перезаписывать их содержимое в массив.

Comment: @Aloisa да, мне приходят уведомления. Я дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо!!! Очень помогли.